# Filtering Voice at Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, voice

I'm trying to eliminate the voice of an mono audio (.wav format) using Matlab. The audio has as voices some recorded sentences of a friend and as music a classical music piece. Untill now I have tried to use a Bandstop filter which goes from 300 Hz to 4000 Hz with sampling frecuency of 48000 Hz and a Highpass filter with a cut-off frecuency of 4000 Hz and sampling frecuency of 48000 Hz and order of 50. Both filters are IIR Butterworth. With any of them I almost kill the music and the voices are not recognisible but they are still there. Could you advise me?(if you could check my code and tell me if I'm doing something wrong appart from the filter I would be very greatful).

```
function d = filtroF(x, L, h)
% d = filtroF(x, L, h)
% x is the signal which we want to filter
% L is the length fo the frames that we want to use
% h is the impulsional response of the filter 

w=2^ceil(log2(L+length(h')-1));
d=zeros(length(x)+length(h'),1);
F1=fft(h',w);
F1=F1';
[filas,columnas]=size(x);
p=ceil((filas/L)-3);

for k=0:p
    X=x(k*L+1:k*L+L);
    X1=fft(X,w);
    X1=filtro(X1); %here i apply a filter in order to remove the voice
    y=ifft(X1);
    d(k*L+1:k*L+size(y),1)=d(k*L+1:k*L+size(y),1)+y;
end

for j=1:length(d)
    d(j,1)=real(d(j,1));
end

end
```

Comment: OK, resolved StackBot, looks it was either a fault or a user with an odd sense of humour. I think your question will be hard to answer though for two reasons: 1) What you are trying to do is very hard in general, and not going to be solved with simple filters. 2) You don't give any sample inputs and expected outputs. "Smart" filtering like this has some hard limits - it *might* be possible to do better than you have so far, but it will depend critically on the nature of the input.